# how do i print a variable inside a servlet

Tags: java, variables, web, servlets

i am having this problem where i have retrieved a value using the post method and i want to print that value how do i do that?

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String comment = request.getParameter("comment");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("qid"));

    out.print(+id+);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
```

Comment: Print where? Into response or to console?

Comment: Where you want to print that value.  System.out.println(comment + " " + id); did you tried this

Comment: not on the console as a response

Answer (score 1):

You can use ServletOutputStream with print() method. Another possibility is to use  [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29).

```
response.getWriter().print(variableToPrint);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can do something like that,

```
String json = "<some_JSON>";

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

, and you will see your response printed in the log console.

In the same way, you can write your value instead of a JSON.